# How to make counter faster than slider?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, counter

I must admit that I'm a very basic javascript user but somehow I found a script that works just good for me, it's a simple image slider. The problem is that the counter is really delayed when it appears, compared to the images.

Here's the part of the code I think I should work on but I have no idea how to solve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#images').cycle({ 
        fx: 'fade',
        next: '#images',        
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 0, after: onAfter });

    function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
        var slide_counter = "0" + (opts.currSlide + 1) + '&nbsp;/&nbsp;' + "0" + opts.slideCount;
        $('#slide_counter').html(slide_counter);
    }
});
</script>
```

If someone could help it will be much appreciated.
Thank you!
Fed

Comment: JSFiddle, please (and HTML)

Comment: I've never used the jQuery Cycle plugin but I have perused the documentation before and there are a ton of options, have you checked to make sure this isn't a pre-made option?

Comment: @ManofSnow here's the JSFiddle, you can't see the images but as you can see after clicking on them the counter update is delayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/q52vD/

Comment: @FedericoFerrari - Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q52vD/1/ - All I've done is change the speed from 1000 to 250 (& used different image links - the first one doesn't work) - there appeared to be a delay of 1 second when using your original fiddle. Does this help?

Comment: @enhzflep it works great!!! Thank you so much. It was easy at the end. : )